# MethodChannel - No implementation found for method on channel

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a method channel between Android and my Flutter project but it keeps throwing 'Missing Plugin Exception'. Tried cleaning, reinstalling etc but it just won't work. While it works inside my other projects.

On Flutter side:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('channel');
```

on button pressed event:

```
  try {
        final int result =
        await platform.invokeMethod('payment');
        print(result);
     } catch (e) {
       print(e.message);
      }
```

Android side:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val channel = "channel"
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channel).setMethodCallHandler {
            call, result ->
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            // TODO
            if (call.method == "payment") {
                result.success(1)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
No implementation found for method payment on channel channel
```

Comment: Are you still getting this error? did you try a flutter clean and run? maybe you could try changing the channel name to something else, maybe channel is a reserved word.
The code seems right to me

Comment: Yep.. no difference... really weird.

Comment: @ItsDjoki are you able to resolve this issue. Even for me same issue

Comment: did you find any solution? @RashmiBhandari

Comment: hi! any solution? having same issue right now